# Box2D Contact Listener , LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am developing game using LibGDX and Box2D . I want to get the force or the impulse when two bodies are collided , But I cant find the right way to do that , how can I use contact listener for getting that impulse or force ?I cant get the impulse using ContactImpulse parameter in postSolve method . Who can help me ?

```
     new ContactListener() {

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold manifold)` method, you can query the velocities of the two bodies that have collided. Using `contact.getFixtureA()` and `contact.getFixtureB()`, you can get the bodies of each fixture, and the use body.getLinearVelocity().

The `preSolve` method is called before box2D actually resolves of the collisions, so at the instant of collision, the impact velocity will still be accessible.

As the manual states: "The pre-solve event is also a good place to determine the point state and the approach velocity of collisions"

You could use the information provided in the `preSolve` such as how heavy the bodies are and how fast they are moving to decide how it would affect your object.